# Definition of "20-strong"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does "20-strong" mean in this [article](https://www.ft.com/content/fd8abff2-8fca-11e6-8df8-d3778b55a923?ftcamp=published_links%2Frss%2Fcompanies_technology%2Ffeed%2F%2Fproduct):

> In the journal Nature the **20-strong** DeepMind team said the DNC provides neural networks with access to previously incompatible external data, such as text encoded in conventional digital form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means there were (perhaps approximately) 20 people on the team.

See this meaning from [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/strong):

[image]

Comment: Does "strong" implicitly imply "many"? Like meaning 20 people is not a small team in this case.

Comment: @CYC - Nope, not really. It's just another way of saying _the 20-member DeepMind team..._